# user account password

Tags: users

I created an account for a standard user and assign a password.
I login as standard user and try to change standard user password and realize that it needs admin user rights to change user password.

I just wanted to know is it possible to create a standard user and let standard user to change his or her password by himself or herself?

Your information and help is great appreciated,

Regards,

Inung

Comment: Which command are you using? Just `passwd` should work.

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen: yes, passwd should work fine, but I think the OP is looking for a graphical way, which I *think* is presently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As the standard user, open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and then type the following:

```
passwd
```

And then enter your current password and then type your new passwords consisting of at least the following:

- 1 special character
- 1 digital character
- 1 alphabetic character

It is not possible to save a password without these criteria met, you'll need super user privileges to assign a simple password to a user.

I am not sure whether there is a graphical way of doing this, will update my answer if I find a simpler, graphical way.